# Reset password with MySQL

Tags: password, mysql

Is there a way to reset an admin account's password by modifying the MySQL directly?

I've found the `craft_users` table where the hashed password is stored but I don't know how to hash a string so that it will be read correctly by Craft.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Craft uses Yii's [`CPasswordHelper::hashPassword`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPasswordHelper) which is a Blowfish hash algorithm, using PHP's [`crypt`](http://php.net/crypt) function with a "blowFishHashCost", which is a setting that can be found through `craft()->config->get('blowfishHashCost')`

You could use the [`SecurityService::hashPassword`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/SecurityService#hashPassword-detail) function to generate a new password, echo it, and update it in the DB manually: `craft()->security->hashPassword('NewPassword');`

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. Is there any way this can be done in a Twig template? Or can the hashPassword function only be called from a plugin?

Comment: i'd setup a temporary plugin (just the handle; `ResetPlugin.php` with an init function, in the init function you "Dump and Die" (`Craft::dd(SecurityService::hashPassword('test'))`) and after that, you delete it :)

Comment: Just in case anyone else needs to do this, I made a plugin here: https://github.com/bravokiloecho/craft-password-helper

Comment: This tweet shows you how to reset the password to `secret` -> https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/1063135843441954816

Answer (score 135):

Future me, looks like you forgot your password again and locked yourself out of Craft. You also made your way back to this Stack Exchange question with @chris' perfect answer. Good! And to make your life *really* easy this time around, I've already generated a password/hash combos for you that works:

```
|--------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  *Password*  |                        *Resulting Hash*                       |
|--------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  password    | $2y$13$i1fEVeKiboWR/Hx07N9JtuSZj46KNueAg0IgpwL2TId0sXN.oyibC  |
|--------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  NewPassword | $2y$13$YA.7RIgllODUDcmQPf/.FuXjOmKJYot5QxpFhhf4og9fdJWsIPWK6  |
|--------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  admin       | $2y$13$Nlvh.kEu8FLIITusfjzQgOIIDryqLnJ3TsV/1UINRCFLfVnjJtILK  |
|--------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

***Update:** The hashing algorithm didn’t change in Craft 3, so the above combo still works.*

***Update:** The hashing algorithm didn’t change in Craft 4, so the above combo still works.*

Comment: Past @carlcs, you are a genius!

Comment: Craft 3: Drop this in a template to render a new password hash `{{ craft.app.security.hashPassword('NewPassword') }}`  Output: `$2y$13$3hcn0v5fVCFB28GS3HNJfez3.MY/HaJnomkESPsy7cEN/Hx9skjLq`

Comment: @SamHernandez ooh nice!

Comment: I come back to this answer with embarrassing frequency.

Comment: @PatrickHarrington you are not alone my friend

Comment: The code to generate the example passwords table above is here: https://gist.github.com/lukeholder/ef09a0e667d864d73244bcd83816ca99

Comment: Is there a way I could use this to get the password hash of users in a craft 2 site so I can add it to an xml file for import to Craft 3 via feedme?

Comment: See these are the kind of people I love. I don't want to know how to generate the damn password, I just want to login into my local version so I can resume work. I will change it later once I log in. Thank you!

Comment: Wish I could vote for this every time I come back and grab this hash. Would be properly embarrassing just how many votes I would have given it now.

Comment: 1st time comment-or, 5th time user. Hat's off.

Comment: This must be the 50th time I've come back to this answer. It feels like an old friend now, always there for me in times of need.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to mess about trying to insert code in the Craft/Yii stack, v3 just calls password_hash():

```
password_hash($your_password_string, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 13]);
```

As a possibly helpful addendum (I was just trying to run the site locally and needed to log in); if you find you still can't login after changing the password via the database and are running PHP locally, it might be because you're accessing via socket and should add this to `config/general.php`:

```
'requireUserAgentAndIpForSession' => false,
```

Comment: I added this `echo password_hash($your_password_string, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 13]);` to web/index.php; got a password on page reloaad then removed it.

Comment: As at 2023-11-10 there is an online bcrypt generator https://bcrypt.online/