# Unable to Log in

Tags: login, password

I am locked out of my site (a new project still on my local MAMP server) and can't log back in. I have tried to rest my password but I haven't received any emails. I also tried to go through MYSQL and reset it through the craft_user file, but this didn't work either. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried to go through MySQL and reset it through the `craft_user` file, but this didn't work either.

You don't mention what you tried, but this method will work: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13966/57