# Reset admin account password using command line interface

Tags: password, console

Can I reset admin password using console CLI interface? Didn't see anything like that when I run the `craft` file directly and it displayed list of commands.

Comment: I'm not sure about reseting via the console, but you can reset your password via MySQL: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13781/reset-password-with-mysql

Answer (score 2):

There's not a native Craft console command that could do that, but plugins can supply there own console commands, so you can write a plugin that added a command to do so.

Craft 2 plugin docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/introduction.html

Craft 3 plugin docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-guide.html

And you can generate plugin boilerplate for both versions here: https://pluginfactory.io/ and there's even a "Console Commands" checkbox you can tick.