# Locked out of my Account, how to get back in?

Tags: error, admin, login, password

This really stressing me out!
When trying to log back in to Craft CMS today after som time my password wouldn´t work. I have not changed it and when trying to reset the password I´m only getting: "There was a problem sending the password reset email."
Is there anyway to find out through eg. my FTP and looking at the backend what the "user/password" is set to and what my reset email is set to?
I have not changed any of this, but since I´m locked out now something must have happened..

Answer (score 7):

This is not actually my answer since it's from Andrew Welch on Twitter here: https://mobile.twitter.com/nystudio107/status/1063135843441954816

> If you have access to MySQL, you can change the admin user password to `secret` using this hash:
>
> `$2y$13$FfVKvo1W1N5Gsba3c19r8uz.x9R5NRQgRu8jmXvOjVCStg1sKGcoW`

Comment: There's a similar, evergreen answer from @carlcs, here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13966/4169 