# CP login error for (only) one user in particular

Tags: error, login

One of our client logins has stopped working.

When you try to login there's a spinner and then `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 ()` error on index.php:1

Sometimes you get a 504 on `index.php?p=admin/actions/users/login` at `jquery.js:9827` instead.

(Running Craft v3.1.34)

Any ideas?

I've tried resetting the password as per https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13966/7356 but this doesn't help, ditto for resetting the password via a 'Copy Password Reset URL' link.

[image]

Comment: Weird... a 504 is a Gateway Timeout. Something blocking that request? Antivirus or firewall on the client computer?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers... I couldn't figure it out @BradBell — eventually just created another user and transferred content over!