# Checking which version of Craft CMS a site is using

Tags: craft3, craft2

I've been asked to look at Craft CMS site where my would-be client has been ghosted by his previous developer. I have no handover information and only FTP and phpmyadmin access presently.

Looking via the FTP it appears that both Craft 3 and Craft 2 versions are installed in the vendors directory.

How can I most easily check which the actual site is being used? From the license key or database perhaps?

Comment: Have a look at the `version` column in your `info` table.

Answer (score 1):

> Looking via the FTP it appears that both Craft 3 and Craft 2 versions are installed in the vendors directory.

Craft 2 didn't use Composer, so wouldn't have a root `vendor` directory, so you're likely running some version of Craft 3.

Like [Oli mentioned](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35548/checking-which-version-of-craft-cms-a-site-is-using#comment41753_35548), if you can connect to the database, you can check the `version` column of the `info` table to see what version of Craft the site using.

If you can't access Craft's control panel, but can access the database, you can use this to gain control panel access: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13966/57